# How to solve $\log n = \frac{\log 2}{10} \sqrt{n}$

Tags: transcendental-equations

I need to solve $\log n = \frac{\log 2}{10} \sqrt{n}$.

I know it is a transcendental function and also hear about generalizes Lambert function (Lambert W-function) could help me to solve it.  But I have no idea about how to apply it.

Comment: Do you mean $(\log 2)\sqrt n$ or $\log(2\sqrt n)$? Or $\log_2(\sqrt n)$?

Comment: What are you talking about this is just an equation? Algebra-PreCalc stuff. You do not need to know the existence of Lambert W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$10\log{n}=\log{(2\sqrt{n})}$

$\log{n^{10}}=\log{(2\sqrt{n})}$

$n^{10}=2\sqrt{n}$

If this is the right interpretation of your question

Comment: THe correct interpretation of my question is $n^{10} = 2^{\sqrt{n}}$. :)

This is what I am trying to solve :)

Comment: @DanielFerreiraCastro You could have answered my question and avoided a lot of people wasting their time by reformatting your question to be clearer.

Comment: Paul, your sentence was "if this is the right interpretation..."  Than I just replied saying what I was trying to find out.  I thank you to point that to me because if it led to a wrong interpretation than I need to reformulate my text for a better understanding.  And since text has no voice tone a simple sentence can be read in diferent ways.  One way is to use the smilley to try to make the sentence a little more mild.  I do not have any intention of offend no one, please accept my appologies if for any trouble I may have cause you.  It was not my intention.

Comment: And no offence was intended nor taken.  It's all good :)

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting it as $$\left(\sqrt{n}\right)^{20} = 2^{\sqrt{n}}$$

Then let $m=\sqrt{n}$ and we need to solve:

$$m^{1/m} = 2^{1/20}$$

Taking the log of both sides, and letting $y=\log m=\frac{\log n}{2}$, you get:

$$ye^{-y} = \frac{\log 2}{20}$$

So $y = -W\left(-\frac{\log 2}{20}\right)$ and $n=e^{2y}$.

Comment: I missed some steps from $m=\sqrt{n}$ to $m^{1/m}=2^{1/20}$

Comment: $m^{20} = 2^m$. Now raise both sides to the power of $\dfrac 1{20m}$.

Comment: Cool.  I followed until the definition of $W=ye^y$. :)
Almost there.  Only missing the steps from $ye^y$ to the last line and how do I evaluate the function in order to find $y$ and then find $n$.

I am trying to understand how Wolfram alpha evaluate this same function.  This is to solve a problem of big-O notation for a function.

One of the solutions is about n=20519.8 that is $\dfrac{400W_{-1}\left(-\dfrac{\log(2)}{20}\right)^2}{\log^2(2)}$ and this is what I am trying to find out how to get there.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\log (n) = \dfrac{1}{10} \log(2 \sqrt{n}) \implies 10 \log(n) = \log(n^{10}) =\log(2 \sqrt{n}),  $$
now since $\log $ is injective this implies that
$$n^{10} = 2 \sqrt{n} = 2n^{1/2} \implies n^{10-1/2} = n^{19/2} = 2 \implies n = 2^{2/19}.$$

Comment: I am trying to solve $n^{10} = 2^{\sqrt{n}}$ :)
Sorry if I led to a wrong interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Paul and Surb already answered if you meant $\log (2\sqrt n)$ but if you meant $\log_2\sqrt n$ instead, here's the solution.

$$\log n=\frac1{10}\log_2\sqrt{n}$$
Since $\log_a b=\dfrac{\log b}{\log a}$
$$\log n=\frac{\log\sqrt{n}}{10\log 2}$$
$$\log n-\frac{\log\sqrt{n}}{10\log 2}=0$$
Bring together the terms in one fraction.
$$\frac{10\log 2\log n - \log\sqrt{n}}{10\log 2}=0$$
Multiply both sides by $10\log 2$
$$10\log 2\log n - \log\sqrt{n}=0$$
Since $n\log a=\log a^n$
$$\log n^{10\log 2} - \log\sqrt{n}=0$$
Since $\log a-\log b=\log \dfrac ab$
$$\log \left(\dfrac{n^{10\log 2}}{\sqrt n}\right)=0$$
Since $\dfrac{a^b}{a^c}=a^{b-c}$ and $\sqrt n=n^\frac 12$
$$\log \left(n^{10\log 2-\frac12}\right)=0$$
Take $\exp$ of both sides
$$n^{10\log 2-\frac12}=1$$
Raise both side to the power $\dfrac{1}{10\log 2-\frac12}$
Note that $1^a=1$ for $a\ne0$
$$n=1$$

Comment: what I meant was an attempt to solve $n^{10} = 2^{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: You should post a new question as to avoid invalidating the answers to this question then.